# What's the best way to "transfer" directives from and to, using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a widget that has the following structure (it's a "plan selector" resume):

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li resume="to" ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="total"></div>
  <ul>
    <li resume="from" ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

my directive is the following:

```js
plans.directive('resume', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<h3>{{step.name}}</h3><div>{{val}}</div>',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {}
  };
});
```

Notes:

- `plans` is an `angular.module('Plans')`
- `items` is some data that is loaded via AJAX, and each item has a `selected` attribute
- they share the same controller as the items that will be selected, that is `PlansCtrl`

What I want:

When the user finishes selecting the items (setting each "selected"), it will only show in the "to" when it's selected, and it will only show in the "from" when it's not selected. I don't want to hard code anything because everything is mounted using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding you right, it's probably better to use [the filter filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/qbGeG/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="x">
    <b>selected</b>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{selected:true}" ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="total"></div>
    <b>unselected</b>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{selected:!true}" ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you need the functionality as a directive, then it would be better to replace the entire `li` element with something like: `<selectableList source="items" />` where your directive just uses `filter` and `ngClick` like I did above.